# Remove duplicates from all columns with condition value>0 in columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I need to remove duplicates from all of the columns.

My data:

```
id   country  publisher   weak     A        B        C
123    US        X          1     6.77      0        0
123    US        X          1       0      1.23     88.7
456    BZ        Y          2       0      56.87    9.65      
456    BZ        Y          2     2.76       0       0  
456    BZ        Y          2       0        0       0
```

I used drop_duplicates-

```
df1=df.drop_duplicates()
```

But I need a condition that will take all the values>0 for each id.

Also, I have more columns than just 'A','B','C' so I'm looking for solution that will take all the columns into account.

Here an example for what I'm looking for:

```
id   country  publisher  weak     A       B        C
123    US        X        1     6.77     1.23     88.7
456    BZ        Y        2     2.76     56.87    9.65
```

Comment: What if a single column of duplicate rows contain more than one value that is >0?

Comment: Not sure if that's your business logic, but it appears to me that you could simply sum A, B and C for each unique id into a single entry, not remove duplicates.

Comment: I have other columns that contain numbers that I don't want to sum.  I will add that to my data, so it will be clear.

Comment: Do you simply mean `df.groupby("id").max()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you your desired output
`groups=df.groupby(['id','country','publisher']).sum()`

Comment: I have other columns that contain numbers that I don't want to sum.  I will add that to my data, so it will be clear.

Comment: I thought u have these columns only

Comment: Then    `groups=df.groupby(['id','country','publisher']).max()`  will work.

Comment: Thanks, It works. My problem now is that I can't drop the id column. I receive this error: "['id'] not found in axis". Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Just simply use  `groups=groups.reset_index()`  and then `groups.drop(['id'],axis=1,inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
cols = ['A', 'B'] # change columns to aggregate more data

def app_func(s):
    return s[~s.eq(0)].bfill().dropna().drop_duplicates()

df.groupby(['id', 'country', 'publisher'])[cols].apply(app_func).reset_index()
```

Comment: How can I change that for more than just 'A', 'B'  columns. I have many more columns to aggregate.

Comment: change the cols variable to your desired columns